# DialogBoxParam did not create a modal dialogbox winapi

Tags: c, winapi, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

I am trying use DialogBoxParam to create a modal dialogbox using VC6.0. But The new dialogbox is not modal, since the back dialogbox is still clickable after the the new dialogbox poped up. And I have no clues about this after searching solutions on google and stackoverflow.

codes:

```
if(lParam->code == NM_DBLCLK)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd,GWL_HINSTANCE);
    //hwnd is current dialogbox which is the parent of the new dialogbox
    int retCode = DialogBoxParam(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG_ADDM), hwnd, AddMember_Proc,(LPARAM)&sdata);
```

resource definition of the new dialogbox:

```
IDD_DIALOG_ADDM DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 374, 240
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
```

Anyone knows that?

**EDIT**

```
BOOL WINAPI AddMember_Proc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_INITDIALOG, AddMember_OnInitDialog);
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, AddMember_OnCommand);
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd,WM_CLOSE, AddMember_OnClose);
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Show your AddMemberProc.

Comment: I have added in the question description. @Xearinox

Comment: When you call `DialogBoxParam` the system disables its owner window. In your code, that owner window is the one you supplied in the third parameter of `DialogBoxParam`, namely `hwnd`. So the obvious explanation is that you passed the wrong window in `hwnd`. Make sure that `hwnd` really is the window you intended to pass.

Comment: Well, hwnd is the dialog who calls DialogBoxParam. AddMemberProc is the process of new dialog. So, hwnd should be the parent of the new dialog, isn't it?

Comment: yes, you are right. It works now. You can edit your comment as an answer. @Xearinox